# Command for returning index of top 3 values in a matrix.

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, rank

For example there is a matrix

1 3 5 
7 9 2 
4 6 8

And how do I find the index of top 3 values?
In this case, it would be, (2,2), (3,3), (2,1) 
What command do I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
m =matrix(c(1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8), ncol=3, nrow=3)
top3 = tail(sort(m),4)
which(m > min(top3), arr.ind = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns a nx2 matrix of row-column pairs:

```
m =matrix(c(1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8), ncol=3, nrow=3)

mm <- arrayInd(which(rank(-m) %in% 1:3,arr.ind=TRUE),dim(m))
```